# Which communities have the most users on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, statistics

I'm just curious. There are so many communities on Stack Exchange; which communities have the most users so far?

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#users

Comment: Stack Overflow has over 11 times as many users as its closest competitor - Super User.

Comment: Even Stack Overflow *Meta* has more users than any other SE site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without any doubt, [Stack Overflow](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#users).

Stack Overflow is the largest community in any way, more users, more questions, more reputation, more visits, more everything.

In the [Stack Overflow Jobs company page](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/stack-overflow), it even says Stack Overflow is the largest technical community *on the entire internet*.

Answer (score 4):

You can cover <s>all</s> most of your curiosity with the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). The following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/477683) answers your question by executing the sql query `select count(*) from users` for every database. I included the meta sites as well.

```sql
-- all databases
declare  db_c cursor for select [name] 
                         from sys.databases 
                         where database_id > 5 -- skip master, temp, model, msdb, Data.SE

declare @db_c_name sysname   -- holds name of db after fetch
declare @sql nvarchar(max) -- holds build up sql string

-- result table
create table #all_users ( site nvarchar(250)
                            , cnt int
                            );

open db_c
fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
while(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin
    set @sql = N'use '+ QUOTENAME(@db_c_name) +';
    insert into #all_users 
    select '''+ QUOTENAME(@db_c_name) +''', count(*) from users';
    exec (@sql)
   fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
end;
close db_c;
deallocate db_c;

select * from #all_users-- all databases
order by cnt desc
```

SEDE is refreshed weekly on Sunday 03:00 UTC. At the day of posting the query yields the following result:

[image: number of users per site]

You might want to checkout questions and answers in the [data-explorer](/questions/tagged/data-explorer) tag. You'll find pre-baked queries there as well as guidance how to leverage its features.

Comment: Why not all? A specific reason?

Comment: @PatrickHofman deleted questions (if not only for counts), hot network stuff, reviews per user to name a few. So you can't answer all your curiousness. I don't want to be bitten by that later. For this OP though it might look you can answer all your curiousness.... hence the distinction.

Comment: Ah, okay. I thought it was directly related to your list below. @rene